# Many-to-many relationship on the same entity without additional join table columns

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, orm

I have an entity that has many-to-many association to itself.

If I needed some additional properties (like asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831186/many-to-many-on-the-same-table-with-additional-columns)) the answer would be to use a new intermediate entity. But without them is it bad practice to use direct many-to-many association to the entity itself?

Comment: what would you do it you wanted to add multiple relations between the same two entities, i.e. image a graph where two vertices might have edges of different colours between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aleksey,

If you have additional columns, **you need a new intermediate Entity**.

> But without them is it bad practice to use direct many-to-many association to the entity itself ?

No, you can if you want **since you do not have additional columns on The joined Table**

Comment: @Aleksey Otrubennikov When i say *many-to-many relationships on the same table are a nightmare to maintain* is because him or her **would like To put all data on a single Table** (No joined Table), Nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Using a mapping table is the optimal way for N to N relations without creating new columns in the mapped tables themselve.

Comment: Maybe my question was not very clear. As I've seen in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831186/many-to-many-on-the-same-table-with-additional-columns/1833365#1833365, many-to-many relationships on the same table are "a nightmare to maintain". So I wanted to know if I actually don't need another entity should I still avoid them.