# JPA One To Many/Many To Many Example

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using:

- Hibernate
- MySQL
- jBoss

I have to create an application that allows user to make friendship.

I'm still in design phase, and I would like to have these tables:

```
- User {_id, name, address} 
 - Friendship {idUserA, idUserB, date}
```

For my purpose I should have a mutual relationship from Users. For example 1 is friend of 2 and indirectly 2 is friend of 1.
So in my table I think to have:

Friendship = {1, 2, ...}

I'm asking how I can simulate this behaviour. I've read his topic: [Many-to-many on the same table with additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831186/many-to-many-on-the-same-table-with-additional-columns) and I've followed this instruction generating database tables from entity (property of hibernate). But in this example when I load my Friend A, I've a list with Friend B and when I load B I haven't user A into List.

How I can implement this damn mutual relationship?

Comment: Can you give some sample code how you designed your entity classes?

Comment: I copy directly from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831186/many-to-many-on-the-same-table-with-additional-columns from  Arthur Ronald F D Garcia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand this sample the mutuality is not implicit. To have friendship relation from A->B and from B->A you have to either add two entries into your table or you have to implement two sets and return  an intersection of the two list:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="myFriends")
private List<MyFriends> myFriends;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="me")
private List<MyFriends> iAmFriendOf;

...

Set<MyFriends> getFriends() {
    Set<MyFriends> friends = new HashSet<MyFriends>();
    friends.addAll(myFriends);
    friends.addAll(iAmFriendOf);
    return friends;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not big fan of OneToMany and especially ManyToMany relationships. I prefer having another table like Friendship as you did. So as far as I understand you are mixing to approaches. To me simplest way is having a Friendship Table and all you need in this table is match two friends so design could be:

```
@Entity
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String address;

}

@Entity
public class Friendship {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="friend_requester_id")
    private User friendRequester;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="friend_accepter_id")
    private User friendAccepter;

    private Date date;

}
```

When listing friends either you could list friendships -as they are another table- or friends using this table. However it is a bit tricky If you would like to list only friends but not so hard. You could have a `getFriends(List<Friendship> friendships, int userId)` method and list friends like:

```
  List<User> friends ...

  Iterator iterator = friendships.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     Friendship friendship = (Friendship) iterator.next();
     if (friendship.getFriendRequester().getId != userId) {
         friends.add(friendship.getFriendRequester);
     } else {
         friends.add(friendship.getFriendAccepter);
     }
  }

  return friends;
```

Another advantage of this implementation you can differentiate who requested to be a friend later (if it is needed).

In my opinion, yes it seems to be complicated and overworked but it is fairly maintainable and less painful.

Comment: A single person can have multiple friendships - which is a 1-Many relationship. How does going via an intermediary table change that? It's still a 1-Many... I'm also curious how you'd store (say) addresses - multiple ppl can live at the same address and a single person can have multiple addresses - without using a Many-Many relationship? Unless I've misunderstood your opening paragraph?

Comment: Yes, sure.. For instance if a user have another friend then it means new record in Friendship table.. So every friendship has a record in friendship table. You can implement multiple address multiple person without using many-to-many relationship. Actually in most applications only one address needed as current address. So you have user and address table in user table many-to-one relationship to adress so you have multiple user in same address. However if you need multiple user in multiple address you need a useraddress table whic has user_id, address_id so now you can have what you need.

Comment: Agreed, address wasn't a great example and usually it's a 1-Many, but what you've described with a table containing `user_id` and `address_id` _is_ a many-many relationship as I understand it (and as per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)).

Comment: Yes, it is many-to-many relationship indeed because logically we are doing a many to many mapping. However implementation is a bit different as many-to-many relationship in same table has some problems. I found a nice page which can explain better than me ;) I hope this makes clearer: [ManyToMany#Advanced](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Advanced)