# How to define a ManyToMany relationship of the same model?

Tags: playframework, ebean

I've got a User model which I'd like to contain a list of "friends":

```
@Entity 
public class User extends Model {

  @Id
  public long id; 

  @ManyToMany
  public List<User> friends;

  ...
}
```

Running this gives me an error (`Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state`) and an evolution file which contains the following table:

```
create table user_user (
    user_id                        bigint not null,
    user_id                        bigint not null,
    constraint pk_user_user primary key (user_id, user_id)
)
```

How do I fix this? Also for bonus points, how can I also get a list of people who are friends of my user?

Comment: Well, that's the answer right there. You just need to apply the evolution. The list of friends is the user object "friends" list.

Comment: aahh..there was something funky going on with my config.  That did seem to work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not recommend to use ManyToMany to the self entity in a real project. Better to create another table, like "Friendship". Look on the answer to this question: [Many-to-many on the same table with additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831186/many-to-many-on-the-same-table-with-additional-columns)

Any way, here is the answer exactly to your question:

You need to configure join table "by arms"

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {

  @Id
  public long id;

  @ManyToMany(targetEntity=User.class)
  @JoinTable(name="friends",
      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_a_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_b_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
  )
  public List<User> friends;
}
```

auto generated evolution script:

```
create table user (
  id                        bigint not null,
  constraint pk_user primary key (id))
;


create table friends (
  user_a_id                      bigint not null,
  user_b_id                      bigint not null,
  constraint pk_friends primary key (user_a_id, user_b_id))
;
create sequence user_seq;




alter table friends add constraint fk_friends_user_01 foreign key (user_a_id) references user (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;

alter table friends add constraint fk_friends_user_02 foreign key (user_b_id) references user (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;

# --- !Downs

SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE;

drop table if exists user;

drop table if exists friends;

SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY TRUE;

drop sequence if exists user_seq;
```